Ignore specific string in flake8 warning when using icecream
I use icecream to support my debugging and a large project I use the install method to make it available in all files.
Unfortunately, flake8, reports that 'ic' is an undefined name
src/forms/frm_player_edit.py:149:9: F821 undefined name 'ic'

Is there any way to suppress this warning just for this string using a global flake8 setting? (I still want it to warn undefined names in general)

you're looking for the builtins setting for flake8
if you're using the ini configuration it looks something like:
[flake8]
builtins = ic


disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer

now to make it work with vscode ...

Add
"flake8.args": [
"--builtins=ic"
] to settings.json in vscode

Use this to suppress the pylance warning "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
"reportUndefinedVariable": "none"
}

In your situation, you can suppress F821 undefined name warning for that specific line or module by adding a # noqa comment with the specific error code.
Here is an example:
ic() #noqa F821

This will tell Flake8 to ignore the F821 undefined name.
I hope this will help you.

Thanks, but one advantage of ic() is that it's fast and minimalist, If i have to add the flake8 comment every time I use it I might as well use print(). Question modified

Yes, you can do this at config level. by adding this on setup.cfg.
[flake8] per-file-ignores = src/forms/frm_player_edit.py:F821 = ic
this will tell Flake8 to ignore the 'F821 undefined name` warning only on this file, but you can also do this at the directory level.
or you can add a # flake8: noqa: F821 comment on top of the file; it will ignore this in the entire file.
